# "transparency" against the light is signal of bad quality dvd media?

Tags: dvd, media

If you put the media against a (monitor's) light and see the other side, does that means that it's a bad quality dvd media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a property of all optical media that I am aware of.  It does not effect their quality or ability to function, it is just the way optical discs are.

Comment: More precisely, a disc is _transparent_ plastic with a _very thin_ layer of reflexive material on it.

Comment: Note, also, that some are not transparent. So my question if it implies in bad (worst) quality.

Comment: @Tom Brito I have never seen a disc that was not transparent. Even an old Playstation disc that was black with heavy graphics printed on the face could be seen through if held up to a really bright light.  I think the transparency of a disc is inconsequential to its quality.

Comment: This is the first dvd I get that is transparent. I have others (LG, Maxtor, etc) and none is transparent. And they work fine, so I'm still not sure if it's or not a quality indicator..